# Python ljust method not working as expected on formatted strings

Tags: python

When using string formatting resulting string is longer than expected.

For example:

```
In [1]: "%s".ljust(7) % "123456"
Out[1]: '123456     '
```

Output string is not 7 characters long.

I'm interested in what is exactly happening 'in the background' to result in such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%s"` is being left adjusted to 7 places first - eg `"%s     "`, and then you're substituting the `'123456'` for the %s... hence the result you get...

```
>>> '%s'.ljust(7)
'%s     '
>>> _ % '123456'
'123456     '
```

You could use:

```
>>> ('%s' % '123456').ljust(7)
'123456
```

Or specify appropriate width in the format string...

Answer (score 1):

The `ljust()` is applied to your formatting string, which, because it is only two characters long, has five spaces appended.

The other string is then interpolated into this.